# Finding the highest value in a range

Tags: excel

How can I find the highest price among the prices with same contiguous label ?

For instance, in the picture below the result of the formula in D6 should be 5 because the formula should consider the lines 4, 5 and 6 only (contiguous lines with label 'a'). Therefore, the prices to be considered should be 3, 4 and 5 and the relevant MAX is 5.

[image]

I started building the formula in steps and the first one is to get the row n# where the max price is and I made this formula `{=MAX(IF($A$2:A5<>A6,ROW()))}` but I cannot even make this to work.

**EDIT**

The solution from Tom Sharpe in this thread is almost perfect. 
What I didn't mention in the initial question is I want to see the MAX in each line. 
Here below is the screenshot with an extra column with what I want to achieve.
[image]

Comment: You can simply use '=MAX(C2:C5)' to get the result. Is there any other condition that needs to be considered here?

Comment: @AnupamChaplot there are no values in column "C". The formula in C6 should look at the same contiguous labels as in line A6 (A4:A5 in this case) in first place, then choose the max value in column "B"

Comment: Why do you ignore rows 8 and 9?

Comment: @SJR Because in line 7 the label is "b". The contiguous label range to consider is A4:A6

Comment: Line 3 is "b" too. Do you mean it has to have a "b" before and after it?

Comment: @SJR it has to have a different label than the one on the current row.

Comment: You're making this quite difficult. Is 5 the result because 5 is the highest value for "a" up to the row containing the formula?

Comment: @SJR Please see below the answer from Tom Sharpe and my edit of the original question.

Comment: Why the downvote by the way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should look something like this (max of a range from the previous row which does not contain the same letter in column A as the current row, plus one, to the current row):

```
=IF(A3=A2,"",MAX(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(A$1:A1)/(A$1:A1<>A2)+1,1)):B2))
```

[image]

Comment: I have amended slightly your formula to meet my new critieria and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I have amended Tom's formula in `=IF(A3=A2,D3,MAX(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(A$1:A1)/(A$1:A1<>A2)+1,1)):B2)) and now I` have the column "E" correctly populated.